# Java: How to make interfaces types interconnected?

Tags: java

How can I get connected a type `I` of interface `Parser` to `validate` method parameter type?

```
public interface Parser<R, I> {
    R parse(I... input);

    interface Validator {
        boolean validate(I... content);
    }
}
```

Right now, I get an error:

```
`my.pack.Parser this`: cannot be referenced from a static context
```

**UPD**

If I add a type `<I>` to my Validator interface I still don't have types relationship.

```
Parser<String, String> p = new Parser<String, String>() {
    @Override
    public String parse(String... input) {
        Validator<Integer> v = new Validator<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public boolean validate(Integer... content) {
                return false;
            }
        };
        return null;
    }
};
```

In my example, the type of Validator should be the same as in Parser - `String`, but not `Integer`.

Comment: You have to think of your `Parser` and `Validator` as completely independent - there is no link between them.  I would require a `Validator<I>` as a constructor parameter to the `Parser`; this would provide the link that you want.

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the type I as a generic parameter to the Validator interface because inner interfaces are always static, so the Validator cannot access the I which is not defined for the interface Parser but only when you instantiate it.